# MAMP Pro 4.0.3: user running apache cannot access this directory

Tags: apache, mamp, mamp-pro

In the standard setup for MAMP PRO, version 4.0.3 in this case, using the htdocs folder for my sites I am getting the "red arrow" indicating a config issue. The highlight message is: user running apache cannot access this directory. Everything works fine but I'd like to get rid of this warning. I'd be happy to hear any suggestions.

Comment: With MAMP Pro, I've always had my directories outside of MAMP's folders. So ~/Projects/[App] where [App] is a project.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand that you will always have this warning/alert when using the MAMP htdocs folder. Your solution is the answer.